# How to achieve high performance routing to Kinesis streams?

Tags: aws, stream-processing

I have consumer pools that consume only events matching a specific attribute (e.g. origin=WINDOWS, the other origin=LINUX).
Since ordering is important (ordering is based on **instanceId**, so this is the partition key) and the throughput is very high, I'm using one Kinesis Stream for each pool (SQS High Throughput might also be possible, but might be hitting the limit there).

Now the problem: Due to system constraints the instance aggregator service must send the events to a single endpoint. Now I have got a problem distributing the event from there and keeping the send order based on instanceId. SNS FIFO service limits are way too low. Setting up a master kinesis stream, then sinking into the different streams based on filtering might not retain the order due to batching in Apache Flink Application on AWS.

The only option I see is building my own router pool behind an NLB that forwards the message based on `origin` to the right kinesis pool, without buffering so the order is guaranteed. Or only have one worker pool that can handle any origin, so monolith. Any other design patterns here?

For example, the message will be like

```
instanceId: 5d1e65c8-c7b1-491c-9c5e-a59da3d7f7f6
origin: LINUX
command: doX
```

```
instanceId: 5d1e65c8-c7b1-491c-9c5e-a59da3d7f7f6
origin: LINUX
command: doY
```

```
instanceId: db81c139-06fb-4f34-8a2e-a0fda1e3c09a
origin: WINDOWS
command: doQ
```

LINUX commands will be handled by worker pool A. WINDOWS by another worker pool (B).
It's important that all messages for the same instanceId retain their order when they are transferred to the respective worker pool. Duplications shall also not happen.

I could let all worker pools read from the original stream, but then they have to filter out 50%+ of the message (e.g. all where origin <> LINUX). I would much rather have them distributed to the right worker pool queue (with order preserved)

Comment: A [picture](https://sequencediagram.org) would be worth a thousand words. You only offered a thousand characters. Also, **numbers** on required performance metrics are pretty essential. You said "SNS too slow!" so I was going to suggest sending fewer, larger messages, until you mentioned "without buffering", which I didn't understand. The `instanceId` is a sequential integer that reveals send order, right? Please update the question to reveal your pain points around reboots, re-ordered messages, dup messages, throughput, and latency.

Comment: @J_H instance id is a unique indentifier for a server. Send order is determined by "received and acknowledged first from the endpoint", like in SNS FIFO. SNS FIFO has a hard limit of 300 messages per second, which is too low. These commands must be execute near real-time, wrong order is bad (e.g. first cd, then mkdir will fail).

Comment: Ok. So SNS only allows sending a message every 3.4 msec. And messages arrive in proper order. To fit within vendor limit, doesn't it suffice to have a buffering layer which waits at least 3.4 msec and then sends a "big" message which has its constituent messages correctly ordered? (Plus you need a 4 msec timeout to fire, in case incoming messages pause.) Also, if feasible, it sounds like it would be helpful for an instance to append a serial counter to each message, so that (instanceId, serial) lets you verify the happens-before ordering, and verify "no drops".

Comment: @J_H With these big messages SNS filtering would not work (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/fifo-message-filtering.html). Hence I couldnt distribute the messages to the right worker queue for the right origin

Comment: Hmm, you've talked me out of SNS, at this point. Sounds like you have performance requirements that other vendors could better address. Splitting across a pair of Windows / Linux pools only gets you a factor of 2x, _if_ they are of comparable volume on the relevant time scale. When adopting a new solution, you probably want more than 2x headroom for future growth. (Also, buffered Windows messages and buffered Linux messages could still preserve ordering, using an 8 msec timeout.)

Comment: Yeah actually there might be more than 2. Might be AWS-Linux, AWS-Windows, Azure-Linux, Azure-Windows etc. I just wished Kinesis Streams hat a filter and fanout pattern based on paritions and their ordering